# how to create a use case diagram for the forum system

Tags: visio, uml

there would be users with different privilages and as a consequence there would be a lot of conditions, so how can i model the conditions in the use case diagrams? for example, the forum manager may create a post or update a post or even delete a post, create a threads or update avialable threads, delete threads, etc.

**1-** should i have different "use case" elements for each task? i mean add an oval/circle element for each task?? like creating an oval for "create a post", an oval for "updating the post",.....

**2-** is it correct to have one actor for each privilage?? like one for anonymuse user, one for logged in user, .....

thanks.

Comment: What do you need the model for? If it's just for yourself, model the parts you feel you don't yet understand properly. If it's to explain the system to a customer, make it make sense to them (maybe just have two users, Helen the sysadmin / maintainer / support / hand-holding service, and Bubba Duh the user / managerial twit).

Comment: currently i'm trying to learn the UML but the resources with a lot of questions and answers are not available. at least i couldn't find any! so i have to stich to stackoverflow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get into conditions and ifs and buts in use cases diagrams. A set of use cases is intended to provide an overview of the system's functionality, and each use case describes an interaction between the system and one or more actors. You want to keep that description simple and succinct.

Each use case should in some way make sense to the actor. To a person using a forum, it does make sense that creating a post is a separate activity from updating one (or responding to one), so that seems like a sensible start to me. You should not be overly concerned with the number of use cases at this stage. The number of use cases does not translate directly into system complexity, and a large number of clearly defined use cases is better than a small number of large, ambiguous ones.

The next step is to *elaborate* your use cases, and that's where you can start talking about conditions. Elaboration is typically done using an activity diagram which describes how the interaction between the actor and the system proceeds, eg Poster initiates post; System checks poster's privileges; System rejects post if privileges are insufficient; etc.

There is of course no right or wrong, but generally speaking it's a bad idea to use actors such as "logged in user" etc, and in fact you should avoid employing a "user" actor at all. Why? Because the interaction is actually between the system and a *person*, whereas a user (account) is an in-system representation of a person's privileges.

In other words, if you find yourself using actors which are in fact concepts from within the system, you've taken a wrong turn somewhere. Every use case must involve a system-external actor, otherwise you're not describing the system from the outside.

A better set of actors for a forum system would probably be Poster, Reader and Manager (and possibly a System Administrator as well).

Comment: oh man thanks a lot! where can i learn this stuff like you already know?? because i can't find anything useful online. especially some practice with answers.

Comment: Really no need to thank me, mate. At SO we really are here to help, and that 'Answered' tick is thanks enough.

Comment: The thing to remember about UML is that the L is significant: it is a language. It helps you _express_ your design or the results of your analysis, but it doesn't help you achieve good results any more than English does. As to resources on these subjects, I'm afraid I don't have anywhere useful to point you to. I studied computer sciense, but what I know of software engineering I've picked up over the years I've worked in this industry.

Comment: i'm wondering why isn't there enough practical resources about uml?

Comment: There are plenty of good books that have been written on UML, with many of them available for under $40 USD. Do a search on UML on amazon or your other favorite online book seller, and browse the available titles. Definitely worth a few bucks to learn something useful...

Comment: well, iknow about that and i've been read a few of them but as i said they're not practical meaning they're not contain enough examples and answers.